# How can I get webrootpath in asp.net core 2 in Program.cs

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, environment

I am told the following is the correct way to seed the database in asp.net core 2.0, i.e, it must be done in program.cs.

I would like to seed the database from a CSV file in the file system. However I cannot figure to access the content root or web root etc in the Main function.

```
        //Program. cs
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var host = BuildWebHost(args);
                using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    try
                    {
                        var context = services.GetRequiredService<EventContext>();

                       // => How can I get the webrootpath here to pass to the seed function? 
                       // => I cannot figure how to access the HostingEnvironment
                       DbInitialize.Seed(context);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ....
                    }
                }
                host.Run();
            }

            public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .Build();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have gotten an answer or found a solution, but what we have done in our projects.

```
public class SeedData
{
    public static void Seed(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
         {
       using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var env = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
                var webRoot = env.WebRootPath;


            }//end using scope
        }// end class
```

and the usage

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var isSeed = args.Contains("/seed");            
        if (isSeed)
        {
            args = args.Except(new[] { "/seed" }).ToArray();
        }

        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        if (isSeed)
        {               
            SeedData.EnsureSeeded(host.Services); 
        }

        host.Run();

    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```